# JSON, getting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm new to JSON and trying to figure out how to get info from a JSON string.
Another question, isn't this not a valid JSOn format, I thought that there needs to be starting ' and ending ' for json files.

In my fiddle, I placed indicators of what I'm trying to get:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hFTN8/37/

```js
var input = {
    "name": "positive", //get this value
    "children": [{
        "name": "product service",
        "children": [{
            "name": "price",
            "children": [{
                "name": "cost",
                "size": 8
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "quality",//Get this value
            "children": [{
                "name": "messaging",
                "size": 4
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "customer service",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Personnel",
            "children": [{
                "name": "CEO",//get this value
                "size": 7
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "product",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Apple",
            "children": [{
                "name": "iPhone 4",
                "size": 10
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
console.log(JSON.input.name[0]);
```

Comment: JSON is NOT an object. JSON is a string. Do NOT call a JavaScript object JSON.

Comment: thanks, I edited and I'll remember that

Comment: [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) may tell you whether it's a valid json or not.

Comment: The first value is just `input.name`, the second `input.children[1].name`, the third `input.children[2].children[0].children.name`.

Comment: what ever you have as the value of your `input` variable is a Javascipt object and not a JSON. If you parse a valid JSON by using `JSON.parse()` then the result you get is this javascript object. Dont confuse yourself. And to access the values of the object you use `.` operator if its just a key value else you use `[0]` indexes if its an array.

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(string);`
Where string is your json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a format for storing data.

You can convert the JSON string to JS object as follow.

```
var javascriptObject = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
```

Now let's assume `yourJsonString` is your code snippet.

To get the value of key `"name"` try `console.log(javascriptObject.name);`

`"children"` is an array of 3 objects. You can access the array objects as follow.

```
var arrayObject=javascriptObject.children[indexValue];
```

You can get the value of key from javascript object using `"."` operator.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

First value can be accessed using : `javascriptObject.children[0].children[1].name;`

Second value can be access using : `javascriptObject.children[1].children[0].children[0].name;`